# CSS hover effect: changing parent and child background colors simultaneously

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="parent">one
    <div class="child">two</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent {
  background: red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
.child {
  background: green;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
/* insted of apply individual */
/* .parent:hover {
     background: blue;
} 
  .child:hover {
    background: black;
  } 
*/
```

I want to change both parent and child background colours. when hover on parent(parent bg:blue, child bg:black). Here the problem is parent & child have the same property(background) but both have different background colours. how can I apply them simultaneously?

Comment: please add a code snippet

Comment: What it is *"simaltinasuly"*?

Comment: See this: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/xxEadbB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change child hover color using this: `.parent:hover .child`

```css
.parent {
  background: red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
.child {
  background: green;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
/* insted of apply individual */
 .parent:hover {
  background: blue;
} 
.parent:hover .child {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="parent">one
    <div class="child">two</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Minal Chauhan. It is working nicely.